# Google Analytics 4 custom events data using measurement protocol show in real-time but are "not set" in exploration reports

Tags: spring, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I need to generate data in a Google Analytics exploration report that isn't triggered by website actions, and I am using the GA4 measurement protocol in Spring. None of the data is updated in the website, so I am sending a daily scheduled report with database data (I am aware this isn't the best use of GA4, but I have no choice). At the moment, I have used my own cookie data, since the location from where the events are sent doesn't matter.

Unfortunately, while the data shows in real-time view fine, a lot of it is shown as "not set" in the exploration reports (these are all custom parameters). My only theory is that the cookie data might be affecting this, but it seems unlikely considering real-time view shows the data just fine. Additionally, even simple events such as a daily user count (using date and count params) does not load in the explorations (not set) 70% of the time. I am not able to load this data from the frontend, but any alternatives to using GA4 in a spring backend could work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have done the following:

- Used the following tutorial to create custom events: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_eoeU2qUn0&t=630s
- Loaded events data before and after creating custom definitions (I'm aware that only the data after the custom definitions should load in the explorations).
- Verified all data sent has shown correctly in the real-time view (there are never any errors sending from Spring to GA4).
- Waited over 48 hours to view data in exploration reports (still "not set").
- Checked nothing in [https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-events-not-showing-up-in-reports/#:~:text=I%20recommend%20double%2Dchecking%20that,of%20the%20standard%20GA4%20reports](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-events-not-showing-up-in-reports/#:%7E:text=I%20recommend%20double%2Dchecking%20that,of%20the%20standard%20GA4%20reports))  and [https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/not-set-in-google-analytics-4/#:~:text=(not%20set)%20means%20that%20GA4,from%20being%20sent%20to%20GA4](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/not-set-in-google-analytics-4/#:%7E:text=(not%20set)%20means%20that%20GA4,from%20being%20sent%20to%20GA4) applies (except the fact I'm using the GA4 measurement protocol).
- Always receive a 204 response code when sending events.
- Validated events created in GA4 event builder site.

Comment: you should wait for at least 48/72 hours after creating customized dimensions, and 24 hours after setting up the GTM in case you are using.   consider using a tool like the Google Analytics Debugger (a Chrome extension) or the GA4 DebugView in the GA4 property itself. These tools can provide more insights into what's being sent to GA, which might help pinpoint any issues for example install the dataLayer extension in chrome browser to check what you are sending to GA.

Comment: Hi Shila, I am not using GTM in this case. Data being sent to GA4 is from a spring backend using only the Measurement Protocol. I have also waited for over a week for data to show in the exploration reports with no luck :(

Comment: you should have at least a javascript to act as listener on you webpage, no? how are you handling the listeners? how you manage to check when a click has been occurred? This is the part that I am telling you that is not working well. please share some code so that I can understand what exactly you are doing

Comment: Hi Shila, unable to share code unfortunately. A scheduled cron job runs in the spring backend to send events with database info every day at 6am. None of the events are triggered by user actions on the website. I know this isn't the best way of using GA, but the client requires this data be sent to GA without user input. I have used my own session id data which should suffice for now (since location of where events were sent doesn't matter in this case). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How come is it possible to send events to GA4 by cron task? Something is wrong. What kind of Event you want to send to GA? the events which is related to the behaviour of users on your website, so you have to have some front-end codes. We also read the info from a scheduled cron program, but this program reads the info which are sent to GA by a javascript. For example the number of clicks on an advertisement is collected by sending a function with specific parameters (dimension) to GA whenever the user clicks on that advertisement. if my js doesn't work, the cron program returns nothing

Comment: The events always send to GA4 with a 204 response code when using them in a cron task. Events sent contain custom parameters for database information. One type of event is a scheduled user count, which uses a date and count params. Another event tracks how many document updates are recorded based on database fields (these documents are not updated in the website at all). Unfortunately, many of the events require sending information that isn't affected by user actions or managed on the frontend. Because it was a client request I used a cron task to get database information as an alternative.

Comment: search on youtube, @AnalyticsMania there are enough tutorials

Comment: Google will use (not set) to obfuscate data that Google believes could expose the user. Some of these settings can be controlled, see: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9019185. You can also look at thresholding:  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630?hl=en.  -- Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seams to me that the client_id must be a string and should contain a dot. In the event section you must have the two parameters session_id and engagement_time_msec, both as numbers (int). The engagement_time_msec should contain 1000. So 10 events with the same client_id and session_id will create an engadged user. Perhaps that will help.